# autowire a list of beans and identify them separately

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web, spring-boot, autowired

I can autowire a list of service `beans` in spring boot but I need a way to pick the one I need using the `name` they have given.

```
@Service("myService")
public class DefaultService implements MyService {
}

@Service("myService2")
public class DefaultService2 implements MyService {
}


@Autowire
List<MyService> services;
```

is it possible to get  **`DefaultService2`** and **`DefaultService`** separately from the list.

Comment: when you extract your `List` try to get your desired `Service` by using the name of the class when you iterate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get your services by name , implement the pattern factory as below:

Your service implementations :

```
public interface MyService {
    void sayHello();
}


public class DefaultService implements MyService {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultService.class);
    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        log.info("Hello from DefaultService");
    }
}

public class DefaultService2 implements MyService {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultService2.class);
    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        log.info("Hello from DefaultService2");
    }
}
```

The factory interface :

```
public interface MyServiceFactory {
    public MyService getMyServiceByName(String name);
}
```

The factory beans :

```
@Configuration
public class MyServiceFactoryBean {
    @Bean
    public FactoryBean serviceLocatorFactoryBean(){
        ServiceLocatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setServiceLocatorInterface(MyServiceFactory.class);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean("myService")
    @Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public DefaultService defaultService(){
        return new DefaultService();
    }

    @Bean("myService2")
    @Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public DefaultService2 defaultService2(){
        return new DefaultService2();
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
   @Autowired
   MyServiceFactory myServiceFactory;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        myServiceFactory.getMyServiceByName("myService").sayHello();
        myServiceFactory.getMyServiceByName("myService2").sayHello();
    }
```

Results :

```
2017-08-11 11:32:31.126  INFO 12827 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.test.DefaultService    : Hello from DefaultService
2017-08-11 11:32:31.129  INFO 12827 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.test.DefaultService2   : Hello from DefaultService2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but have you tried this?:

```
@Autowire
MyService myService;

@Autowire
MyService myService2;
```

The field name should be hint enough to Spring. Otherwise use [`@Qualifier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) as explained by albert_nil.

Comment: is it possible to get the bean i want from the  autowired list .

Comment: @Priyamal Well, yeah, you can always iterate it and call `isinstance` on the items.

Comment: thanks.  that is possible too but i actually need a way to do this by using the bean name.

Comment: @Priyamal This is probably not easily possible, since that reflection info is lost once you have the list.

Answer (score 1):

Add @Qualifier annotation:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myService")
MyService myService;
```

Comment: is it possible to get the bean i want from the  autowired list .

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myService")
MyService myService;
```

Or use resource annotation. It should work.

```
@Resource
MyService myService;



@Resource
MyService myService2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to iterate your bean in the `List` and identify each bean using reflection api `.getClass().getSimpleName()`. This will return the String name of your class.

```
for(MyService service : services) {
    if(service.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("DefaultService")) {
        MyService defaultService = service; // This is DefaultService class
    }
    if(service.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("DefaultService2")) {
        MyService defaultService2 = service; // This is DefaultService2 class
    }
}
```

With this, you will know what would be the Service you are using.

Answer (score 0):

i can take out the beans seperately by sorting **`autowire order`**.naming is not needed now.

```
@Order(value=1)
@Service
public class DefaultService implements MyService {
}

@Service
@Order(value=2)
public class DefaultService2 implements MyService {
}
```